# Meaning of 'Adapted by [another person's name]' written on book cover?

Tags: publishing, academic-writing, copyright

Some of the books have written on their covers this:

> Adapted by [another person's name]

Content of such textbooks is more or less same, maybe some new chapters are added.

What does 'adapted by' mean? How does it work? Who grants permission for the adaptation: publisher/original author?

Comment: Hi threeA's! Welcome to Writing.SE! Please take a look at out [tour] and [help] pages, you might find them useful. Regarding your question, are you talking about fiction books or academic books?

Comment: @Galastel It's about academic textbooks and usually such textbooks are written originally by foreign authors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permission is given by the entity that owns the original copyright, which may be the author, the publisher, or some third party that bought the rights to it. That could even be the person adapting it, or **their** publisher.

"Adapted" usually means updated and edited, perhaps with new examples or experiments, to meet a specific need (or to modernize it). For example, if technology has changed the field in question so a 1970 era textbook on sociology isn't good enough to teach a modern class, due to the advent of social media, the Internet, the acceptance of homosexuality and gay marriage, the changing sexual attitudes, etc. But enough of the textbook containing sociological methods, basic statistics and experiment design are still valid, so somebody just wants to "adapt" that textbook to modern times.